# Minimize the sum of distances between a circle and two fixed points

Tags: geometry, optimization, circles

[image: Image 1]

> $\textbf{Question:}\ \ $Find a point D that lies on the circle O and the sum $\dfrac12\,BD+AD$ is minimal
>
> (The radius of the circle is $4$)

$\ $

I have solved this question algebraically by constructing equations, and the answer is $2\sqrt{10}$

However, the calculation involves many radicals, which becomes too complicated.

So could anyone provide some hints of finding an easier $\textbf{geometric}$ approach?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Do you have the radius of the circle? Is it $\frac{1}{2}(BD+AD)$?

Comment: @CYKwong Oops, sorry for this mistake. The radius is 4, and I just edited it into the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given two points $P$ and $Q$, the locus of points $T$ such that $TP/TQ$ is constant is a circle. In particular, the given circle is the locus of points $D$ such that $BD/B'D=2$, where $B'$ is on $OB$ and $OB'=2$.

The question can then be rephrased as follows: find $D$ on the circle such that the sum $B'D+AD$ is minimal. But this is easy, because $B'$ is inside the circle and $B'D+AD$ is minimal when $B'$, $D$ and $A$ are aligned.

In that case, from Pythagoras' theorem we get $B'D+AD=B'A=2\sqrt{10}$.

[image]

Comment: Nice! This is exactly the "easy" geometric solution I am looking for, thanks